# Is there a way to come back on last page in Navigation stack, and not execute OnApearing method in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So, I have `Page1`, with some input fields that my user already filled, and, there is a button that opens a new Page (let's call it `Page2`).

This is the code I used to go on `Page2`.

```
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new Page2()));
```

This is the code I used to came back on `Page1`.

```
private async void GoBackButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

Now, I'd like to, somehow, when user finishes what he had on `Page2`, he presses the button, called `GoBack`, then he comes back on the `Page1`, and the `OnApearing` method of `Page1`'s ViewModel is **NOT** getting executed. Is this doable?

Not sure if important, but I'm using VS22, on Windows10.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to bypass such an important event as `OnAppearing`, however, you can have custom logic inside the `OnAppearing` method that either does something or skips it based on whatever condition. Example: The `OnAppearing` method loads some data when you initially open the page, but when you're returning to it from `Page2`, the loading is skipped.

Comment: use a simple `bool` to track whether or not you've completed any page init, and only execute it when false

Comment: @MichalDiviš Love the idea, but, how do I know if I'm returning from the `Page1`?

Comment: I can't think of a lot of easy out of the box techniques to do this. Prism (https://prismlibrary.com/docs/) has a very robust navigation pattern you can implement if your willing to buy into that. Otherwise, if your trying to get some data from a modal type window, you could consider wrapping then navigation in a TaskCompletionSource and pass an action the modal page can execute to tell the initial page to pop it, and then you can re-enable the onappearing method once thats done. I can post a more comprehensive example if thats what your trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'm using in some of my apps. The logic is: Page1 loads data on the first load and then only reloads data when reload requested.

Here's an example:

Page1.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    private bool _isFirstLoad = true;
    private bool _isReloadRequested;

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task OpenPage2Async()
    {
        //navigate to Page2
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new Page2(() => _isReloadRequested = true)));
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        if (_isFirstLoad)
        {
            _isFirstLoad = false;
            ReloadData();
            return;
        }

        if (_isReloadRequested)
        {
            ReloadData();
            _isReloadRequested = false;
        }
    }

    private void ReloadData()
    {
        //reload data...
    }
}
```

Page2.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    private readonly Action _requestReload;

    public Page2(Action requestReload)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _requestReload = requestReload;
    }

    private async Task GoBackAsync()
    {
        //invoke callback to set Page1's _isReloadRequested to true
        _requestReload?.Invoke();
        //go back to Page1
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good pattern. NOTE: I wouldn't name the parameter `callback`, because that gives no indication of its purpose. A name like `requestReload` would be preferable.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve you're right, thank you. I'll edit the answer to use a better name.

Comment: This seems to be the right thing. Thank you.